# Best way to optimise Python loop with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

What is the best practice with Python loops to optimise the runtime ?
I know that I should avoid as much as possible python loop, but for case where I can't use any numpy functionality to satisfy my needs, how can I write loop that are still performante ?

Here is an exemple :
I'm trying to write an algorithm that take a numpy array, and return all the first element where the sum is inferior to a value MAX.

Here is an instance : array = `[1, 4, 5, 1, 8]`, MAX = 7
The return would be `[1, 4, 1]` here.

I don't think there is any numpy functionality that would help me there.

Here is a python loop that would work for this problem :

```
acc = 0
buff = []
for elem in array:
    if acc + elem <= b:
        buff.append(elem)
        acc += elem
```

What is the best solution to optimise a such loop ?

And if there is no other solution, maybe I should write this loop in C or something and find a way to connect it to my numpy array ?

Comment: There are tools like `numba` that allow you write c-like code that gets compiled and run fast.  They aren't quite as flexible as pure python/numpy but may be worth the effort for time critical steps.  An experienced `numpy` user can often rewrite a problem to take advantage of the existing compiled `numpy` methods, but there's no short cut or drop-in method for doing that.

Comment: This is a simple version of the knapsack problem.  `numpy` as a rule is not a good tool for searching problems like this.  You are testing alternatives sequentially (or in some sort of search tree).  That doesn't fit with the "vectorized/parallel" nature of most `numpy` code.  We can do: `np.cumsum([1,4,5,1,8])`, but we can't readily backtrack and skip the `5` to get closer to 7.

Comment: @hpaulj yes totally. That the answer I was looking for.
rumba look to fit perfectly in such case, I just added the number decoration and I literally gained *10 in executing time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple algorithm outline **which does not solve the given problem**, left here for completeness in the discussion.

- You already have an array `a = [1 4 1 5 8]`
- Copy it, slicing off the first element, so you have `b = [4 1 5 8]`
- Make an expression that adds the two arrays;
- Filter `a` according to that sum: return the `a` value wherever `a+b < MAX`

I trust that you can handle the coding from here.

---

Thanks for the clarification: you're looking for an accumulated sum, not merely pairings.  No, there is no optimization, because you have to check each element in sequence.  If you wish, you can build the list with a careful `reduce` operation, but the execution time won't be notably better.

Comment: I'm not sure that you totally understood the problem, I can't get how your algorithm can output the solution. But actually my question is more on how to optimise python loop that can't be done with numpy built in functions.

Comment: There would be no loop; it would be with vector operations.  NumPy broadcasting is alreayd optimized for you.

Comment: Yes sure but you're algorithm don't solve this problem at all

Comment: It's the NumPy equivalent of [ma for ma, mb in zip(a, b) if ma+mb < MAX].  PLease explain how this not solve your posted problem?

Comment: It's just not the good algorithm.
if a = [1, 4, 5, 1, 8], b = [4, 5, 1, 8] and MAX = 7,
```[ma for ma, mb in zip(a, b) if ma+mb < MAX]```would return ```[1, 5]```which is not the good answer.

Comment: I see it now; you're looking to accumulate a sum less than 7, not find pairings whose sum is less than 7.